# Op amp Output DC Level

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

In almost every book, they say the output DC level of the op amp is at VDD / 2. How can we assume that the output DC level is at VDD / 2. For example, in the 5T OTA, the output node is between two transistors at the bottom and one transistor at the top. So, the output swings from 2*Vov all the way to VDD - Vov. For maximum swing, the DC level should be placed between these two voltages, and not at VDD / 2? So, why does every book mention the output at VDD / 2?

Comment: Answering the first question only. Please don't ask two large questions in one question, but move the second question to a separate question post. However, this is just a problem with misinterpreting something: I bet the texts you've read were referring to *differential* input voltages, not common mode.

Comment: I've removed the second question since each question post should contain one major question. You are welcome to post a new question for your second one.

Comment: Your question is not universal to all op-amps or all op-amp circuits. The books, if they say that, refer to a certain circuit configuration, maybe with a single supply. You need to give more information which book or which circuit specifically you mean.

Answer (score 0):

> In almost every book, they say the output DC level of the opamp is at VDD / 2.

Never read that in a book! It's *somewhere between the positive and negative supply*, yes, but the fact that it can't be *exactly* the middle directly followed from the fact that opamps are supposed to reject noise. If they reject noise on the positive supply, how would their output follow variations in the supply voltage?

Also, don't forget that your book definitely told you that your opamp has enormous voltage gain - so that 20 nV difference due to one pin being slightly closer to 5V supply and current creeping over? That would also non-medium-point your output. You'll really want to check whether you might be over interpretating your books there!

No, the voltage that an opamp output has when there is zero input difference is usually exactly defined by the external circuitry: all useful opamp designs have some form of negatives feedback (unless their output is never meant to be anything but the highest or lowest possible). And that clearly relates the output voltage to the voltages on the inputs of that circuitries - and not to the midpoint of supply.

Try it out! Take any of the basic opamp configurations and apply your golden opamp rules: the output voltage does not depend on the supply voltages, as long as they are high/low enough and as long as there is some negative feedback, thanks to the very large amplification of the opamp.

Comment: Are you saying that it is not necessary to worry where the output common mode voltage of the opamp is during opamp design since this can be done using feedback later?

Comment: Not later: inherently through the feedback. This is integral to how you use an opamp, not an afterthought!

Answer (score 0):

You can assume the output voltage of an op-amp with zero differential voltage is (V+ + V-)/2 and you'll get good results. If V- = 0 (single supply) then it's Vdd/2.

Just keep in mind that in a real op-amp there is also an input offset voltage that will mean that it will only be Vdd/2 for some unknown differential input voltage that could be a few millivolts one way or the other. Amost always, Gain * |Vos(max)|  is >> the supply voltage. For example, for the op-amp mentioned below Vos is typically +/-1.1mV (+/-12mV maximum) and gain is typically 700V/mV.

You refer to the "5T OTA" which is not a complete op-amp as you would be able to purchase. If you look at the internals of a CMOS op-amp such as [this TI one](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc27l2.pdf), you'll see additional stages:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but you response didn't clarify anything. Also, saying that `the "5T OTA" which is not a complete op-amp` is wrong. It is used in integrated circuits to drive capacitive loads.

Comment: @LeonhardEuler that doesn't make it any more complete!

Comment: You omitted the qualification "as you would be able to purchase". That's in there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Biasing the output to half the supply voltage is a general rule of thumb and makes life easy because the inputs can then be biased to mid-supply using two equal value resistors.

But, unless you have an output rail-to-rail op amp or the positive and negative saturation voltages are equal distance from the supply rails, biasing of the output to mid-supply doesn't necessaraly mean that there will be equal maximum head room in either direction.

Take the LM358 for example. It can drive its output almost to 0 V in a negative going direction but saturates at almost 2 V below the positive rail in a positive going direction. In this case biasing the inputs (and therefore the output)  to Vdd/2 would allow less output swing in the positive direction than the negative direction and in this situation a careful designer might want to bias the inputs and output a little below Vdd/2 to equal up and maximize the headroom in either direction. So in the case of a LM358 running on a 0 V to +5 V supply it would be pragmatic to bias the op amp to, say, (5 V - 2 V)/2 just to allow a symmetric maximum output swing and that extra bit of headroom.

This technique of slightly off-setting the bias becomes more important for lower supply voltages when biasing to mid-supply can make the asymmetric maximum output swing more apparent.

Answer (score -1):

The output voltage of an opamp cannot swing past its supply rails: Vdd (positive), and Vss (negative).  Sometimes Vss is connected to GND (0V), other times it is connected to a negative supply.  When an op-amp is used in a circuit, then of course the output voltage will be whatever it has to be - and it would be a very useless device if its output voltage was *always* **"Vdd/2"**.

The term **"Vdd / 2"** is just a figure of speech, what it means is that the op-amp is operating in its linear region *as an amplifier with a very large gain*, and that its output node voltage is free to move, either up or down, in accordance with simple rules.  That is: the actual output voltage is determined by the external components connected to the op-amp, not the op-amp itself.

When analysing the *internal operation* of an op-amp, it helps to think that the output voltage is located mid-way between the two supply voltages. If there is only one power supply, say +12V, meaning Vdd (positive) is connected to +12V, and Vss (negative) is connected to 0V, then the mid-way voltage is +12 / 2 = 6V.

However, if there are two power supplies, say, +6V, and -6V, with Vdd connected to +6V, and Vss connected to -6V, then the mid-way voltage is 0V.  The calculation equivalent to "Vdd / 2" would be:
Vout = (Vdd + Vss) / 2
= (+6V + (-6)) / 2
= 0V.

"Vdd / 2" is just a special case of "(Vdd + Vss) / 2)" where Vss = 0V.

But as far as the op-amp is concerned, it does not care if it's power supply terminals are connected to +12V & 0V, or to +6V & -6V, the voltage **across** the power terminals is the same: 12V.  And furthermore, the voltage of the output is **mid-way between** the voltages of power supply terminals.

Note: sometimes the node Vdd is called Vcc, and the node Vss may be called Vee.  Vcc and Vee were used back in the day when op-amps were made from bi-polar transistors, and Vcc and Vee were just a way of naming nodes, in this case, nodes associated with BJT collector and BJT emitter, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, but you're just talking about random things I didn't ask about.

Comment: My answer was focused on this part of your question: //"So, why does every book mention the output at VDD / 2?"  Your question provided no other context, so I assumed it was a general question regarding the biasing of opamps and why the term "Vdd/2" exists.  // If you were more interested in a specific application, eg: ensuring maximum available signal swing for the output node, then perhaps your question should have specified that (BTW, the answer by @User350400 addresses that particular question).  Cheers.